# UITextView dynamic width according to text inside in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uikit

I'm working to make a chat bubble like in iMessage. I have to use UITextView to get advantage of DataDetectors to detect urls, phone numbers and addresses automatically. My view hierarchy is like;

```
-UITableViewCell
 -ContentView
  -ChatBubbleContainerView
   -UITextView
```

`ChatBubbleContainerView` have constraints of

- 10-pt left, right, top and bottom margins --> `ContainerView`

UITextView have constraints of

- 10-pt of left, right, top and bottom margins --> `ChatBubbleContainerView`

I want to achieve a behaviour to make the text view automatically expand its height and width according to its content inside e.g. text. But the text view has no **intrinsic content size**.

**These are what i have tried and got wrong results**

1. Overriding the `intrinsicContentSize` property of text view but it's
   not working too.
2. Giving a width constraint to the `ChatBubbleContainerView` and changing it to result of `sizeThatFits()` method
3. Giving a width constraint to the `ChatBubbleContainerView` and changing it to result of `text.boundingRect` method

**These are the results i've got**

1. It's not working properly and the cell is not laying out as expected as i scroll the table view
2. It's working but the initial width of cell in the nib is 375-pt which is good for 4.7 inch devices but when i switch to devices like iPhone SE which has 4 inches at the initial table view load or cell insertion, the cell's width is calculating according to 375-pt not 320-pt. After scrolling cell, the layout is laying out as expected.
3. Same with 2.

When i try same layout with `UILabel` it's working as expected. As you may know `UILabel` has intrinsic content size.

Thanks

Comment: Have you disabled scrolling for your `UITextView`? If not, do so. It should then behave in the same manner as a `UILabel`

Comment: @DonMag I've disabled scrolling of UITextView to prevent the scrolling to be active

Comment: OK, then you have some other constraints causing the issue. Try this test: create a new view controller; add a `UITextView`; turn off scrolling; constrain it `Leading: 20`, `Top: 100` and `Trailing >= 20`, **no** height or bottom constraint; change the default text from the Lorum Ipsum filler to "Test" and run the app. Your text view should be 1-line tall and only as wide as the word "Test". As you type, the text view will expand horizontally until it needs to wrap, and then it will expand vertically.

Answer (score 0):

TextView Contraints are good you need to made some changes on ChatBubbleContainerView constraints.

ChatBubbleContainerView constraint:

- top, leading, bottom -> 10 pts
- MaxWidth(GreaterThanOrEqual) to contentView, for instance **0.85** or you can set TrailingConstraint with maxConstant(GreaterThanOrEqual to contentView.

you need to set the maxWidth then only ChatBubbleContainerView will be responsive.